# How to update data from vue-tables-2 after action from Template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-tables-2

I'm using a custom component as a column on vue-tables-2, to do that I'm using a vue-component as described here: [vue-components](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2#vue-components)

I've created a button that opens a modal to the user confirm some information, and after that I make a request to the backend and the record is changed on the database.
Now I want to refresh the data on the table, but I don't know how to do that. The documentation said about using the *$ref*, but this is not an option because my component is not the parent.

How can I do that?

Links to the code:
[Component using 'vue-tables-2'](https://github.com/afucher/aera/blob/master/app/src/components/payment/ListPayment.vue)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="payment">
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="onlyPending"  @change="filterPay()">Apenas pendentes</input>
            <v-server-table url="/api/payments" :columns="columns" :options="options" ></v-server-table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import pay from './ModalConfirmPay.vue'
import {Event} from 'vue-tables-2';
    export default {
        name: "AeraListPayment",
        props: ['groupId'],
        data: function(){
            let groupId = this.groupId;
            return {
                columns: ['name','value','course','due_date','paid','installment','pay'],
                options: {
                    responseAdapter : function(data) {
                        data.data = data.data.map(payment => {
                            payment.paid = payment.paid ? "pago" : "pendente";
                            return payment;
                        })
                        return data;
                        },
                    headings: {
                        installment: 'Parcela',
                        paid: 'Status',
                        value: 'Valor',
                        due_date: 'Vencimento',
                        pay: 'Ação',
                        course: 'Curso',
                        name: 'Nome'
                    },
                    templates : {
                        pay
                    },
                    customFilters: ['onlyPending','groupId'],
                    initFilters:{groupId:groupId,onlyPending:true}
                },
                onlyPending: true
            }
        },
        methods: {
            filterPay(){
                Event.$emit('vue-tables.filter::onlyPending', this.onlyPending);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

[Component that is being used as a custom column:](https://github.com/afucher/aera/blob/master/app/src/components/payment/ModalConfirmPay.vue)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click.prevent="show">Pagar</button>
        <modal :name="modalName">
            <p>Confirma o pagamento de {{data.value}} ?</p>
            <p>Parcela: {{data.installment}}</p>
            <p>Vecimento: {{data.due_date}}</p>
            <button @click.prevent="pay">Confirmar</button>
            <button @click.prevent="hide">Cancelar</button>
        </modal>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import PaymentService from '../../services/PaymentService'
let service = new PaymentService();
export default {
    name:"ModalConfirmPay",
    props: ["data"],
    computed: {
        modalName: function () {
        // `this` aponta para a instância Vue da variável `vm`
        return `confirm-pay-${this.data.clientGroup_id}-${this.data.installment}`
        }
    },
    methods: {
        show () {
            this.$modal.show(this.modalName);
        },
        pay ( ) {
            service.pay(this.data)
                .then(this.hide());
        },
        hide () {
            this.$modal.hide(this.modalName);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you can share some code, so we can better understand your question

Comment: Hello @PavelKovalev, I have already posted the link for the source code. I edited the question to make it more clear :)

Comment: Yeah, it was a long day :-) I added those pieces of code to the post so others can see it right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First, defined an EventBus if you don't have

  **EventBus.vue**

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    export default new Vue()
```

- In ListPayment.vue, import `EventBus` and listen for `refresh-table` event. Note that I add `ref="table"` to vue-tables-2 element

  ```
  <template>
    <v-server-table ref="table" ... />
  </template>

  <script>
  import EventBus from './EventBus.vue'

  export default {
    mounted() {
      EventBus.$on('refresh-table', this.refreshTable)
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
      EventBus.$off('refresh-table', this.refreshTable)    
    },
    methods: {
      refreshTable() {
        this.$refs.table.refresh();
      }
    }

  }
  </script>
  ```
- Finally, emit event in modal

```
    pay() {
        service.pay(this.data)
            .then(() => {
              EventBus.$emit('refresh-table')
            })
            .then(this.hide());
    }
```